# Using Django Models in standalone script - Website not updating

Tags: python, django, sqlite, gunicorn

I am trying to update records in my `SQLite3` DB using the `Django` `ORM` and the `update()` function.

I can see that after running the `update()` function in my standalone script, the database has in-fact been updated, but the changes are not reflected on my website until I restart `gunicorn` with:

```
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```

I suspect the issue has to do with the way I import my models into my standalone script.

```
ROOT_DIR = /path/to/root/dir

sys.path.insert(0, ROOT_DIR)
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'AppName .settings')

import django
django.setup()

from main.models import Bet, Investment, Profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

Bet.objects.filter(id=4).update(revenue=10)
```

This bit of code is being run once a day on my server.
I would expect to see the updates reflected on my site without having to restart gunicorn.

More context: I am running a `create()` function in the same standalone script which is updating the database and being reflected on my site as expected without having to restart `gunicorn`.

Comment: django orm filter query  returns a queryset  not one object

Comment: Almost certainly the problem is with how you're displaying the items on your website, but you haven't shown any of that code.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is not a direct answer to your problem, but for a standalone script in Django, I suggest using [custom management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/). This way you avoid the setup and environment variables.

For example, you could write a script `main/management/commands/my_script_1.py` (read the docs about why it goes there):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from main.models import Bet, Investment, Profile

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.write('Before: {}'.format(
            [(e.pk, e.revenue) for e in Bet.objects.filter(id=4)]))

        # do the update of rows
        Bet.objects.filter(id=4).update(revenue=10)

        self.stdout.write('After: {}'.format(
            [(e.pk, e.revenue) for e in Bet.objects.filter(id=4)]))
```

And then you can invoke the script like this (in linux):

```
$ ./manage.py my_script_1
```

Or, if you have your code inside an virtual env, but want to call your script form a `cron` job:

```
$ crontab -l
0 5 * * * cd /path/to/project && /path/to/project/.venv/bin/python /path/to/project/manage.py my_script_1 > /dev/null 2>&1
```