# How to run a python script in django propject which has multiple django models in it

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a script that I want to run from terminal inside a django project and that script is a python script and it has multiple django models in it .So how can I run that script since I am not able to run it directly.Also everything resides inside docker container.

Comment: Please add example code of what you are trying to do, and also any error messages you got from what you tried already.

Comment: Execute that script by making it a management command.

Comment: Your question is not very specific. What does this script run? You said "it has multiple django models in it", so why you're not using Django models.py for this? 
Anyway, seems like something that a management command could solve like @ans2human said.

Answer (score 0):

For a standalone script that uses Django models, I suggest using [custom management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/).

For example, you could write a script `main/management/commands/my_script_1.py` (read the docs about why it goes there):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from main.models import SomeModel1

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.write('SomeModel1: {}'.format(
            SomeModel1.objects.count()))
```

And then you can invoke the script like this (example in `linux`):

```
$ ./manage.py my_script_1
```

Here is one of [my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54159258/9225671) about the same topic.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `django-extentions`[link](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runscript.html) for this problem and whenever we want we can run our script from django-console. Here we can populate fixture data or run custom command what we want.